# Can not send attachments via multidict as suggested in mailgun Api

Tags: python, request, urllib3, mailgun

I'm using python 2.7 and requests 
This is taken from mailgun's docs :

```
def send_inline_image():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/messages",
        auth=("api", "key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0"),
        files=MultiDict([("inline", open("files/test.jpg"))]),
        data={"from": "Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>",
              "to": "sergeyo@profista.com",
              "subject": "Hello",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!",
              "html": '<html>Inline image here: <img src="cid:test.jpg"></html>'})
```

When trying to send the attchments as described I get the following error:

```
    files=MultiDict([("inline", open("embeddedImages/bg.png"))])
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\requests\api.py", line 87, in post
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\requests\safe_mode.py", line 37, in wrapped
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\requests\api.py", line 42, in request
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\requests\sessions.py", line 230, in request
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\requests\models.py", line 507, in send
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\requests\models.py", line 366, in _encode_files
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\requests\packages\urllib3\filepost.py", line 80, i
n encode_multipart_formdata
TypeError: 'list' does not have the buffer interface
```

Any ideas?

Regards,
Omer.

Comment: mailgun has only basic and very poor examples. I really do not like that! I was struggling to use this API, but now I gave up. Here in stackoverflow a lot of similar questions without answer. I do not think mailgun is the best solution in terms of newsletter/maillist..